# calling a web service from WordPress

Tags: web-services, wordpress

How would I call a web service from one of my pages?

It would go something like this:

1. I call a web service with a parameter in side my page or form.
2. The web service returns a value
3. I store that value in a hidden field.

I can't seem to find any instructions on the web to help me to this inside a WordPress form/page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you describe the type of web service please?

Comment: it's a SOAP service created in .NET ( not sure if that's the info you are looking for, dierre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [PHP SOAP Extension](http://devzone.zend.com/article/689) to invoke a SOAP web service.